# sed - specific regex(s) based on prior given user "options"

Tags: regex, awk, sed, sles

I am currently trying to merge several xml files via the following code:

```
rex_xh="-e '/^ *<\?xml[^>]*>$/d' -e s/^ *<\?xml[^>]+>//'"
rex_el="-e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'"
rex_ts="-e "'s/^[ \t]*//'
while read xmldat ; do
        cat $xmldat | sed $rex_xh $rex_el $rex_ts >> "$OUTDIR/$OUTFILE" ; 
done << "$files"
```

which should essentially be executed (for each file) as:
`cat $xmldat | sed -e '/^ *<\?xml[^>]*>$/d' -e s/^ *<\?xml[^>]+>//' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' -e "'s/^[ \t]*// >> "$OUTDIR/$OUTFILE"`

However when trying to execute this, i get this error message:
*sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `'*

If I execute the command without the variables and instead enter the sed commands directly, it works fine. What am i missing? Am I doing something wrong with the variable expansion?

Based on (later given) user input, all 3, only 2 or only 1 of the given regular expressions should be used on the file(s).
The current setup should
-remove xml headers
-remove empty lines
-remove tabs and spaces in the beginning of new lines.

**Input Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15" standalone="no"?>
<RootNode xmlns="http://stub/example">
        
    <ExampleBase someattr="val">
                
        <InnerNode>Example</InnerNode>

    <ExampleBase someattr="val">

</RootNode>
```

**Expected result (when header removal, space removal and empty line removal is wanted)**

```
<RootNode xmlns="http://stub/example">  
<ExampleBase someattr="val">
<InnerNode>Example</InnerNode>
<ExampleBase someattr="val">
</RootNode>
```

**Expected result (when only space removal and empty line removal is wanted)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15" standalone="no"?>
<RootNode xmlns="http://stub/example">  
<ExampleBase someattr="val">
<InnerNode>Example</InnerNode>
<ExampleBase someattr="val">
</RootNode>
```

**Input Example 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15" standalone="no"?><RootNode xmlns="http://stub/example"><ExampleBase someattr="val"><InnerNode>Example
                              </InnerNode>

    <ExampleBase someattr="val">

</RootNode>
```

(And yes, we get that kind of weird formatted xml)

**Expected result (when header removal, space removal and empty line removal is wanted)**

```
<RootNode xmlns="http://stub/example"><ExampleBase someattr="val"><InnerNode>Example
</InnerNode>
<ExampleBase someattr="val">
</RootNode>
```

**Notes:**

- The files are not always valid xml files, hence I cant use xmllint or other xml tools

  - e.g. no closing tag
- The header dows not always is alone on the first line, sometimes it is not succeeded by a line break.
- The different regexes (e.g rex_xh) will later be optional and controlled by user input, hence the "necessity" to wrap them in variables
- In the future it should be easy, to add new "options", hence another reason for using the "options" in variables.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Good that you have posted your efforts in your question, please do post samples of input and expected output also in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13 
Just edited the question to be more precise and hold expected output as well as an input example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following `awk` code to deal with few edge cases added by OP into the question now. Written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```bash
awk -v RS="^$" '
match($0,/^<\?xml version="[^"]*" encoding="[^"]*" standalone="[^"]*"\?>/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  gsub(/\n/,"",val)
  gsub(/>[[:space:]]*</,">\n<",val)
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+</,"<",val)
  gsub(/>[[:space:]]*</,">\n<",val)
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using 2 conditions in `awk` program. 1st: If a line is NOT having value(matching by regex `^<\?xml version="[^"]*" encoding="[^"]*" standalone="[^"]*"\?>$`) AND its NOT NULL, then using `gsub` function(s) to get output as per need and print that line's value present in val variable..

---

---

***EDIT by OP - Implemented Solution***
After fiddling around and due to the help,comments and answer from @RavinderSingh13 The following code is the final solution(snippet for the important part):

```
rm_xmlhead=1;  # Option given via user input (later)
rm_tabspac=1;  # Option given via user input (later)
rm_emptyln=1;  # Option given via user input (later)
while read xmldat ; do
  cat $xmldat | awk -v rem_xh=$rm_xmlhead -v rem_ts=$rm_tabspac -v rem_el=$rm_emptyln ' {
          if(rem_xh) { sub(/^ *<\?xml[^>]+>/,"") }
          if(rem_ts) { sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"") }
          if(rem_el && $0 =="" ) {next}
          print
      }' >> "$OUTPUT" ; 
done << "$files"
```

This removes empty lines, leading spaces and tabs, xml headers and is easily expandable if any "new" requirements arise...also it gives me the possibility to later make each of the removals optional.

Comment: I've deleted my previous comment, as I posted it without seeing your edit (sorry for that)
I just upüdated my question a little bit. I will fiddle a little bit with awk now and will report later :) (If you have any other ideas or suggestions, feel free to post them ;D)

Comment: @Stahler, With your shown samples only, please do try my EDIT code once and let me know how it goes, it worked fine for me with your shown samples of 2nd file.

Comment: @Stahler, Once you are ok with EDIT solution I will remove the very fist one, since my EDIT code works in both type of files, when I tested it.

Comment: @Stahler, have you checked my solution also? It works with both the scenarios  well.

Comment: @Stahler, Request you to not to edit your question, rather you could add your solution in answer section please.

Comment: yes i tried it, and it works great, however, I was not able to make the different parts "optional" (empty lines, tab spaces, headers) with your code, thus I changed it a bit (see updated question). If you update your code to be "customizable" I will gladly mark it as accepted :) (and later on remove unneccessary comments here to prevent confusion when others stumble upon this)

Comment: @Stahler, I have removed my initial answer and kept only edited answer + your edited/added answer one in post, cheers.